# Node js routing confusion

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, routes, render

Is there any better way to handle that? I just wanted to render a html page with css and client js.

```
app.get('/:path', function(req, res) {
    let path = req.params.path

    if (path.endsWith(".html")) {
        res.render("./" + path)
        return
    }

    fs.readFile("./" + path, null, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.send(data)
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express js provides express.static function

**app.use(express.static('foldername'))**

inside folder you can create html,css js file, So your url would be localhost/filename.html
filename.html directly call your new folder file.

for your reference:
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html